# Los objetos pasan por referencia en Python

Tags: python, poo, class, paso-por-referencia

He visto en mucha información del paso del variables por referencia y por valor en Python, pero estoy muy confundido con el paso de objetos:

```py
class Primera_Clase():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = "hola"


class Segunda_Clase():
    def __init__(self,primera_clase):
            primera_clase.variable = "adios"

p = Primera_Clase()
s = Segunda_Clase(p)
print(p.variable)
```

**Resultado:** adios

¿Porqué pasa esto?

Comment: ¿Qué esperarías que pasará?

Comment: Que el objeto no cambie

Answer (score 1):

No hay "paso por referencia" o "paso por valor" en Python.

Todos los pasos son "por referencia" en un cierto sentido. El sentido es que en python **todas las variables** son referencias (o si prefieres verlo así, se puede decir que todas son punteros).

Incluso cuando haces una sencilla asignación como:

```
n = 1
```

se está creando en realidad en memoria un objeto de tipo `int`, que contiene el valor 1, y se está haciendo que `n` sea una referencia a ese objeto. Es decir, la línea anterior sería más o menos equivalente a esta otra en Java:

```
n = new Integer(1);
```

Una asignación como la siguiente:

```
x = n
```

copia en realidad *la referencia*, de modo que al final tanto `x` como `n` "apuntan" al mismo objeto.

El paso de parámetros es equivalente a una asignación. Si la función se declara con un parámetro `x`, por ejemplo así: `def f(x):` y se invoca pasándole otro parámetro `n`, por ejemplo así: `f(n)`, lo que ocurre es que nada más arrancar la función se hace la asignación `x = n`, y ésta, *como todas las asignaciones en python*, asigna la referencia, por lo que el parámetro `x` en realidad apunta al mismo objeto que la variable `n`.

### Inmutabilidad y mutabilidad

Ahora bien, esto no significa que por el hecho de estar "apuntando" al mismo objeto, puedas cambiar el valor de éste. Eso sólo puedes hacerlo en datos que sean de tipo *mutable*.

Para empezar, si reasignas la variable, por ejemplo así:

```
n = 1
x = n
x = 2
```

eso no hace que `n` tome el valor 2. De hecho, la cosa queda más clara si lo reescribimos en *pseudojava*:

```
n = new Integer(1);
x = n;
x = new Integer(2);
```

En la primera asignación `n` queda "apuntando" a un dato que vale 1. En la segunda, `x` y `n` quedan apuntando al mismo dato (que vale 1, por lo que tanto si imprimes `x` como si imprimes `n` verás lo mismo). En la tercera línea `x` se reasigna, por lo que *ya no apunta al 1*, sino que pasa a apuntar al 2. Esto no afecta a `n` que sigue apuntando al 1.

Un entero además es *inmutable*, lo que significa que no hay forma posible de cambiar el "objeto 1" para que contenga un número diferente. Una operación como ésta:

```
n += 100
```

no cambia el "objeto 1" al que apuntaba `n` por el valor 101. En cambio, crea un nuevo objeto de valor 101 y reasigna la referencia `n`. Es decir, equivale básicamente a:

```
n = new Integer(n+100);
```

### ¿Qué datos son mutables?

Son mutables las listas, los diccionarios y los objetos. Pero son mutables porque tienen una sintaxis *extra* (más allá de la mera asignación) para acceder a sus elementos.

Si por ejemplo `l` es una lista, puedes usar `l[0] = 100` para cambiar el primer elemento de la misma. Esto no cambia la referencia `l`, que *sigue apuntando a la misma lista*. En cambio, modifica directamente la lista a la que apunta.

Análogamente ocurre con un diccionario, en el que `d["clave"] = valor` permite modificar directamente el diccionario apuntado por `d`.

Y en el caso de los objetos, si `obj` es un objeto (es decir, una referencia aun objeto), entonces `obj.campo = valor` permite modificar directamente el objeto apuntado por `obj`. La referencia sigue apuntando al mismo objeto, pero el valor del `campo` habrá cambiado (siendo aún más precisos, el `campo` es otra referencia y se cambia a dónde apunta).

Debido a esto, es posible modificar *indirectamente* este tipo de valores. Considera el siguiente ejemplo:

```
p = Primera_Clase()
q = p
```

La primera línea crea un objeto nuevo, y hace que `p` "apunte" a él. La segunda línea no crea ningún objeto nuevo. Hace que `q` apunte al mismo objeto al que apuntaba `p`. Por ello si ahora hacemos:

```
q.variable = "Hola"
```

estaremos modificando directamente el objeto apuntado, y por tanto indirectamente eso tendrá efecto en `p`, ya que `p` apunta al mismo objeto. Así que `p.variable` también valdrá `"Hola"`.

Si combinas esto con lo que te conté antes de que un paso de parámetros en el fondo no es más que una asignación, comprenderás por qué una función puede modificar el objeto que ha recibido como parámetro (de hecho, esto es lo que hace `self`, que no es más que una referencia a un objeto particular que va a ser modificado por las funciones de la clase).