# ¿Hay referencias en python?

Tags: python-3.x

Sabemos que en C++ podemos pasar una variable a una función por referencia, y editarla desde el cuerpo de la función. Ahora bien esto me pasó en Python con dos funciones parecidas en el valor que retornan, solo que una edita la variable original y la otra no:

```
import random
 
def mix(i):
    # mix a list ( i = original list)
 
    a = [] # indexes already copied
    m = [] # copied elements
    c = 0 # a counter
    r = 0 # just a random number
 
    while c < len(i): # access all elements
        r = random.randint(0, len(i) - 1) # generate the first random number
 
        while r in a: # check if the generated number was already used
            r = random.randint(0, len(i) - 1) # generate another one
 
        m.append(i[r]) # add the element with the random index to the mixed list
        a.append(r) # add the random number to the used indexes
        c += 1
 
    return m
 
def sort(i):
    # sort a list in ascending order (i = original list)
 
    c = 0 # a counter
 
    while c < len(i) - 1: # access all elements
 
        # check if the element is in the right position
 
        if c == 0: # if we are checking the first element
 
            if i[c] < i[c + 1]:
                c += 1
                continue
 
        elif c > 0 and c < len(i) - 1: # if we are checking an intermediate element
 
            if i[c] < i[c + 1] and i[c] > i[c - 1]:
                c += 1
                continue
 
        elif c == len(i) - 1: # if we are checking the last element
 
            if i[c] > i[c - 1]:
                c += 1
                continue
 
        # if it is not in the right position, the execution will pass to here
 
        if c == 0: # if we are moving the first element
            i[c] += i[c + 1]
            i[c + 1] = i[c] - i[c + 1]
            i[c] -= i[c + 1]
 
            c = 0 # start again
            continue
 
        elif c > 0 and c < len(i) - 1: # if we are moving an intermediate element
 
            if i[c] > i[c + 1]: # if it has to be moved to right
                i[c] += i[c + 1]
                i[c + 1] = i[c] - i[c + 1]
                i[c] -= i[c + 1]
 
            if i[c] < i[c - 1]: # if it has to be moved to left
                i[c] += i[c - 1]
                i[c - 1] = i[c] - i[c - 1]
                i[c] -= i[c - 1]
 
                c = 0 # start again
                continue
 
        elif c == len(i) - 1: # if we are moving the last element
            i[c] += i[c - 1]
            i[c - 1] = i[c] - i[c - 1]
            i[c] -= i[c - 1]
 
            c = 0 # start again
            continue
 
    return i
 
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 7, 9, 8, 3, 0]
 
print("============")
print("a = ", a)
print("b = ", b)
 
mix(a)
sort(b)
 
print("============")
print("a = ", a)
print("b = ", b)
print("============")
 
Output:
============
a =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b =  [6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 7, 9, 8, 3, 0]
============
a =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
============
```

La salida del código muestra que al usar la función mix sobre la variable a, esta no es editada, pero al usar la función sort sobre la variable b, la lista original sí cambia... ¿Porqué?
También si reasigno i por m al final de la función mix, la variable original cambiará. ¿Significa que en Python se pueden reasignar variables desde una función?

Comment: La pregunta debe incluir el código.

Comment: Ok, lo siento...

Comment: Esta respuesta responde tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/518851/158880