AGREGAR FILA O COLUMNA CONSIDERANDO LOS INDICES DE CADA POSICION Y TODAS LAS POSICIONES ADYACENTES
Realizar un algoritmo en Python para llenar datos de una matriz de orden n*m con
números enteros aleatorios de más de dos cifras. Si la matriz es orden cuadrática agregar una fila caso contrario agregar una columna. Para obtener los datos de la nueva fila o columna considerar los índices de cada posición y todas las posiciones adyacentes, si la suma de los índices es par el nuevo dato es la suma de los dígitos pares; caso contrario el nuevo dato es la suma de los dígitos impares.
Este es mi codigo y se me agrega una nueva fila o columna correctamente pero con numeros randomicos como hago lo de tomar los indices ver si es par o impar y segun eso sumar y llenar las nuevas filas o columnas en la misma matriz
import random

def llenar_matriz(filas, columnas):

    if filas == columnas:
        filas += 1
    else:
        columnas += 1

    matriz = []
    for _ in range(filas):
        fila = []
        for _ in range(columnas):
            numero = random.randint(10, 999)
            fila.append(numero)
        matriz.append(fila)
    return matriz



def sumar_digitos(numero):
   
    suma = 0
    while numero > 0:
        digito = numero % 10
        if digito % 2 == 0:
            suma += digito
        numero //= 10
    return suma


def imprimir_matriz(matriz):
    for fila in matriz:
        print(fila)


# Ejemplo de uso
filas = 3
columnas = 3
mi_matriz = llenar_matriz(filas, columnas)
imprimir_matriz(mi_matriz)


Viendo el código veo que se está partiendo de la matriz ya modificada es decir con la columna o fila adicional, lo que no es consistente con el print que colocaste de matriz original. Deberías crear la matriz en el orden que te solicita el usuario y esa si sería tu matriz original, luego entrega esa matriz a otro método que realice la validación de la columna o fila adicional.
Sería algo como esto:

import random

def llenar_matriz_original(filas, columnas):

    matriz = []

    for _ in range(filas):

      fila = [random.randint(10, 999) for _ in range(columnas)]

      matriz.append(fila)

    return matriz


def editar_matriz(matriz):

  #Se necesita conocer el orden de la matriz para poder saber si se agrega una fila o una columna

  num_filas = len(matriz)

  num_columns = len(matriz[0])

  agregar_fila = False

  if num_filas == num_columns:

    num_filas +=1

    agregar_fila = True

  """

  Se realiza la validación y se determina si se agrega la fila o la columna

  En este punto yo creé una fila o columna nueva llena de ceros, puedes dejarla así y luego pasar esta 

  nueva matriz a otro método que realice los cálculos de suma para estos valores o hacerlo en este 

  punto.

  """

  if agregar_fila:

    # Agregar una fila de ceros a la matriz

    nueva_fila = [0] * num_columns

    matriz.append(nueva_fila)

  else:

    # Agregar una columna de ceros a la matriz

    for fila in matriz:

        fila.append(0)

  return matriz



def imprimir_matriz(matriz):

  for fila in matriz:

      print(fila)

    

# Ejemplo de uso

filas = 3

columnas = 3

mi_matriz = llenar_matriz_original(filas, columnas)

print("Matriz original:")

imprimir_matriz(mi_matriz)



# Agregar una fila o columna con ceros

#Recuerda usar el .copy() para no modificar la matriz original

nueva_matriz = mi_matriz.copy()

mi_matriz_con_sumas = editar_matriz(nueva_matriz)

print("\nMatriz con fila o columna adicional:")

imprimir_matriz(mi_matriz_con_sumas)




Recuerda que en Python hay tipos de datos que se pasan por referencia y otros por valor. Lo que quiere decir Las variables que contienen tipos de datos inmutables, como enteros, flotantes, cadenas y tuplas, se pasan por valor, el resto por referencia. Por valor quiere decir que se crea una nueva variable y la original no se ve afectada. Por referencia, se comparte la dirección de memoria por lo que se va a modificar tu variable original.
En este caso se pasa por referencia porque la matriz, es un tipo de dato que se pasa como referencia, ten cuidado con esto porque estás modificando tu matriz original, para evitarlo usa .copy()
Para terminar de ayudarte, sería muy útil que coloques un ejemplo de una matriz original y otra modificada con su nueva columna o fila para así comprender bien el proceso de sumas que se deben hacer porque no es claro en tu descripción.

Python hay tipos de datos que se pasan por referencia y otros por valor Es una confusión común. En realidad, Python pasa "por asignación". Al ejecutar fun(x, y]), Python crea dos variables a las que asigna los respectivos valores (a=x y b=y).  La función trabaja con esas variables. Todo depende de si los valores son mutables o no. Si x es inmutable, cuando modificas a, esta última variable se desvincula del valor recibido y se le asigna un nuevo objeto. Si y es mutable (una lista, por ejemplo), entonces el cambio en b se refleja en y.

Al desvincular a y asignarle un nuevo valor, x sigue referenciando el valor original y a se pierde al retornar. Mientras tanto, si el parámetro es mutable (una lista, por ejemplo), la referencia no se cambia, y tanto b como y siguen apuntando al mismo objeto.

Para más información https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/518829/los-objetos-pasan-por-referencia-en-python

TENGO ESTE CODIGO PERO NO ME SUMA BIEN
import random
def llenar_matriz(filas, columnas):

    if filas == columnas:
        filas += 1
    else:
        columnas += 1

    matriz = []
    for _ in range(filas):
        fila = []
        for _ in range(columnas):
            numero = random.randint(10, 999)
            fila.append(numero)
        matriz.append(fila)
    return matriz


def sumar_digitos(numero):
    suma = 0
    while numero > 0:
        digito = numero % 10
        suma += digito
        numero //= 10
    return suma


def suma_aditivos(fila, columna, matriz):
    suma = 0
    if (fila + columna) % 2 == 0:
        # Sumar adyacentes pares (arriba, abajo, izquierda, derecha)
        if fila > 0:
            suma += sumar_digitos(matriz[fila - 1][columna])
        if fila < len(matriz) - 1:
            suma += sumar_digitos(matriz[fila + 1][columna])
        if columna > 0:
            suma += sumar_digitos(matriz[fila][columna - 1])
        if columna < len(matriz[0]) - 1:
            suma += sumar_digitos(matriz[fila][columna + 1])
    else:
        # Sumar adyacentes impares (diagonales)
        if fila > 0 and columna > 0:
            suma += sumar_digitos(matriz[fila - 1][columna - 1])
        if fila > 0 and columna < len(matriz[0]) - 1:
            suma += sumar_digitos(matriz[fila - 1][columna + 1])
        if fila < len(matriz) - 1 and columna > 0:
            suma += sumar_digitos(matriz[fila + 1][columna - 1])
        if fila < len(matriz) - 1 and columna < len(matriz[0]) - 1:
            suma += sumar_digitos(matriz[fila + 1][columna + 1])
    return suma


def agregar_fila_o_columna(matriz):
    nueva_matriz = []
    for i, fila in enumerate(matriz):
        nueva_fila = []
        for j, elemento in enumerate(fila):
            nueva_fila.append(elemento)
            suma = suma_aditivos(i, j, matriz)
            nueva_fila[j] += suma
        nueva_matriz.append(nueva_fila)
    return nueva_matriz


def imprimir_matriz(matriz):
    for fila in matriz:
        print(fila)


# Ejemplo de uso
filas = 3
columnas = 3
mi_matriz = llenar_matriz(filas, columnas)
print("Matriz original:")
imprimir_matriz(mi_matriz)

# Agregar una fila o columna con la suma de los dígitos de los números adyacentes
mi_matriz_con_sumas = agregar_fila_o_columna(mi_matriz)
print("\nMatriz con suma de dígitos en fila o columna adicional:")
imprimir_matriz(mi_matriz_con_sumas)


Esto es una respuesta?? o es otro codigo que deberia ir en la pregunta??? hay un boton editar, usalo y agrega todo lo necesario en la pregunta...

matriz = []
for fila in range(dimension_matriz):
    matriz.append([])
    for n in range(dimension_matriz):
        matriz[fila].append(".")


Es necesaria una explicación. El código por si solo no es respuesta.
